# Value Cannot be Coerced to Number (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to create a Google Sheets document about Mario Kart of all things, and am dealing with a large number of times measured in the format m.s.000, like 1:17.489. I have created a custom number format of m.s.000, as one does.

Attempting to subtract a pair of these durations using =B3-C3 results, however, in a cell value of "#VALUE!", and an error stating the following: "Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '1:17.489' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.".

Google Sheets is not recognizing that my custom *number* format is actually a number. I refuse to convert my times to raw seconds (1:17.489 → 77.489). I have also tried =VALUE(B3)-VALUE(C3). This results in the same "#VALUE!" text, with a new error: "VALUE parameter '1:17.489' cannot be parsed to number." Why isn't it parsing to a number? Can I somehow force it to parse 1:17.489 as 77.489? Can I force it to accept my number format as, well, a number?

I have tried only the above two formulas, with both my custom format (m.s.000), and Sheets' default "duration" format.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just curious...do you have to have that third number at the end, or could it be rounded up to have just 2 digits at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on [How to Format Time to Millisecond Format in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/format-time-to-millisecond-format-in-google-sheets/#Convert_Time_with_Milliseconds_Entered_in_Text_Format_to_Time_Format) on *infoinsprired*.

I'll summarise here.

**Custom Time Format**

- Just to clarify: you said `I have created a custom number format of m.s.000`. I hope you *meant* that you actually created a `custom TIME format` of "m:s.000" where m= Minute, s=Second and 000 = Milliseconds.

**Data Entry**

- You **must** to enter the time as HH:MM:SS.000

  - Yep, even though your custom time doesn't include an "hour" value, you must enter it anyway - for example 0:01:17.489
  - if you don't enter the time in this format, the spreadsheet will treat it as text. You can always test this using `ISDATE()` Vs `ISTEXT` (and even `ISNUMBER` if you're interested).

**Convert text value to date value**

- `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(("00:"&B3:D8)*1))`

  - where "B3:D8" is an example of a range array.
  - You can also enter this as a simple formula referencing a single cell.